# Integrating exponential pdf

Tags: integration, probability-distributions, self-learning

I am having problems with an integral while trying to find the mgf of the exponential pdf

$ \int_0^{\infty} e^{tx} \beta ^{-1}e^{-x/ \beta}$ where $\beta$ and $t$ are constants.

I can get to this stage:

$\beta^{-1} \frac{1}{t -1/ \beta} e^{(t-(1/\beta))x}$ evaluated from 0 to $\infty$, however I do not understand why it does not evaluate to infinity (assuming my integration was correct). Rather the book gives $ \frac{1}{1 - t \beta}$.

Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\int_0^\infty e^{\left(t-\frac1\beta\right)x}\beta^{-1}dx=\left.\frac1{\beta t-1} e^{\left(t-\frac1\beta\right)x}\right|_0^\infty=\begin{cases}\infty,&t-\frac1\beta\ge0\\{}\\\frac1{\beta t-1},&t-\frac1\beta<0\end{cases}$$

since for example

$$t-\frac1\beta>0\implies e^{\left(t-\frac1\beta\right)x} \xrightarrow[x\to\infty]{}\infty$$

You try the other cases.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. I am still a bit confused why if t - 1/Beta = 0, the integral wouldn't resolve to 0

Comment: @Eliza Not really. That's an easy though slightly tricky one: $$t-\frac1\beta=0\implies\int_0^\infty e^{\left(t-\frac1\beta\right)}\beta^{-1}dx=\frac1\beta\int_0^\infty dx \leftarrow\text{this clearly diverges}$$